# Why is my output parameter in stored procedure called from Entity Null?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I am calling a stored procedure and declare an output paramters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_getIsReadyForProcess
@VideoId INT ,
@val INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
-- LOCK ROW UNTIL END OF TRANSACTION
        SELECT * FROM dbo.ProcessStatus WITH (ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE VideoId = @VideoId
```

And then setting the value throughout the transaction

```
  --If there is no row count
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    SET @val = 0
END

-- If video is already in process
ELSE IF @statusCode > 1
BEGIN
    SET @val = 0
END

...... more if blocks

          -- RELEASE LOCK
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
```

Here is the c# code for getting the output parameter:

```
        using (var db = EntityFactory.GetInstance())
        {
            ObjectParameter objParam = new ObjectParameter("val", typeof(int));
            db.usp_getIsReadyForProcess(videoId, objParam);

            return (int)objParam.Value == 1;
        }
```

... But then objParam.Value is null no matter what I do.

So I dig a little deeper and uncover an exception that was handled already,

Message: 
Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.

What am i doing wrong? I tried type(bool, int32, string) .. nothing works

Comment: I'm not sure EF supports output parameters.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881359/i-cannot-get-the-output-parameter-when-use-function-import-by-entity-framework

Comment: @DavidTansey Hmm, good link. So you need to ensure the procedure has executed before checking the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure returns a resultset, due to this line:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ProcessStatus WITH (ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE VideoId = @VideoId
```

You can either change the SQL to something like:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ProcessStatus WITH (ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE VideoId = @VideoId
```

Or you can capture the resultset in your code:

```
var resultSet = db.usp_getIsReadyForProcess(videoId, objParam);
```